# Is it true that $\langle \left(P(\mathbb{1}_A)\right)^2, \mathbb{1}_A\ \rangle \geq \mu(A)^2$?

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a probability space, and let $P: L^2(X,\mu) \to L^2(X,\mu)$ denote the orthogonal projection onto some closed subspace of $L^2(X,\mu)$ that contains the (almost everywhere) constant functions. Is it then true that for any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ we have that
$$\langle \left(P(\mathbb{1}_A)\right)^2, \mathbb{1}_A\ \rangle \geq  \langle \mathbb{1}_A , 1 \rangle ^2 = \mu(A)^2,$$
or even that the LHS above is positive when $\mu(A)>0$ ? I know that
$\langle P(\mathbb{1}_A), \mathbb{1}_A\  \rangle \geq  \mu(A)^2 ,$ because of Cauchy-Schwartz, since $P$ is a projection and $P(1)=1$, but can't work out the other one.

Of course, by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ I mean the inner product in $L^2(X,\mu)$.

$\\$

Update: It turns out that
$$\langle \left( P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\right)^2\ , \mathbb{1}_A \rangle \geq \mu(A)^4.$$
Indeed, just notice that $\mathbb{1}_A=(\mathbb{1}_A)^2$ and then use Cauchy-Schwartz to obtain that
$$\langle \left( P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\right)^2\ , (\mathbb{1}_A)^2 \rangle \geq \langle P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\ , \mathbb{1}_A \rangle^2,$$
which in turn is at least $\mu(A)^4$ as I state in the question.

Comment: Since the closed subspace contains the constant functions, it follows $
\langle 1_A - P(1_A), 1 \rangle =0.
$ Not sure what to make out of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that
$$\langle \left( P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\right)^2\ , \mathbb{1}_A \rangle = \langle \left( P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\right)^2\ , \left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)^2 \rangle  \geq \langle P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\ , \mathbb{1}_A  \rangle ^2$$
by Cauchy Schwarz, but then $\langle P\left( \mathbb{1}_A \right)\ , \mathbb{1}_A  \rangle ^2 \geq \mu(A)^4$, as was mentioned in the question, so we have that the LHS is positive and a slightly different lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be the projection onto the closed subspace $V$.
The projection satisfies
$$
\langle 1_A - P(1_A),\ v \rangle =0 \quad \forall c\in V.
$$
Since that subspace contains all constant functions, it follows that
$$
\langle 1_A - P(1_A), 1 \rangle =0.
$$
In particular, if $V$ is *equal* to the subspace of constant functions, then $P(1_A) = 1 \cdot \mu(A)$ and
$$
\langle (P(1_A))^2, 1_A \rangle = \mu(A)^3.
$$

Setting $v = P(1_A)$ in the above equality gives
$$
\| P(1_A)\|_{L^2}^2 = \langle 1_A, P(1_A)\rangle,
$$
but there is nothing that suggests a lower bound of $\langle ( P(1_A))^2, 1_A \rangle$.

Comment: I didn't claim equality, but that the quantity is greater than or equal to $\mu(A)^4$. I included details in the update. Do you agree with my claim?

Comment: yes. It is an usual way of writing Cauchy-Schwarz, but seems to be true. Note that my calculation with $V=$ space of constant functions shows that the lower bound is at most $\mu(A)^3$ not $\mu(A)^2$.

Comment: Indeed, but the question is more general and I think the bound $\mu(A)^3$ might not always hold. However, $\mu(A)^4$ is always a lower bound.